# How to write custom property deserializers in jackson

Tags: java, json, kotlin, jackson, deserialization

I have a lot of different classes that have a property that needs custom deserialization.

Example:

```
data class Specific(val a: String, val b: String) // <-- Needs special deserialization
data class Foo(val value: String, val sp: Specific)
data class Bar(val something: Int, val sp: Specific)
```

I have tried creating a custom deserializer using the `StdDeserializer`. And this only works if I write the deserializer for the actual class (`Foo` and `Bar`), but I only want to write one for the `Specific` type.

*As I'm using Kotlin I would love the non java Annotated way to to it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `ObjectMapper` that you're going to use to do the deserialization, first register a custom deserializer for the `Specific` class. It will then use that when deserializing instances of this class, regardless of whether you're deserializing them directly, or as a property of some other object being deserialized.

For example you could do something like this:

```
class SpecificDeserializer() : StdDeserializer<Specific>(Specific::class.java) {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Specific {
        // Deserialize
    }
}

val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(SimpleModule().also {
    it.addDeserializer(Specific::class.java, SpecificDeserializer())
})

val foo = mapper.readValue<Foo>(...
```

This is explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). Note that for serialization the same approach can be taken.